# How do I send release key with directInput?

Tags: c#, keyboard, directinput

I want to send keys using direct Input.I was able to send key press.However i do not know how to send the key release to avoid keeping key pressed.

Here is my code:

```
struct INPUT
{
  public UInt32 type;
  public ushort wVk;
  public ushort wScan;
  public UInt32 dwFlags;
  public UInt32 time;
  public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
  public UInt32 uMsg;
  public ushort wParamL;
  public ushort wParamH;

}

enum SendInputFlags
{
  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002,
  KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = 0x0004,
  KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE = 0x0008,
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 nInputs, 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] INPUT[] pInputs, 
  Int32 cbSize);

public static void StrokeW()
{
  INPUT[] InputData = new INPUT[1];
  ushort ScanCode = 0x11;
  InputData[0].type = 1;
  InputData[0].wScan = (ushort)ScanCode;
  InputData[0].dwFlags = (uint)SendInputFlags.KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
  SendInput(1, InputData, Marshal.SizeOf(InputData[0]));
}
```

Note : I tried this [Simulating Keyboard with SendInput API in DirectInput applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications) and i was not able to make it work

Comment: Please don't remove a question after someone has taken the time to answer it for you.

Comment: i am the one who answered it ,the first answer is unhelpful :)

Comment: Ah okay, that's fair.  I didn't notice your answer before.

Answer (score 2):

The code you demonstrated appears to not be following the advice on the link you posted, which actually shows the *keyup* which you aren't doing:

```
INPUT[] InputData = new INPUT[2];

InputData[0].type = 1; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
InputData[0].wScan = (ushort)ScanCode;
InputData[0].dwFlags = (uint)SendInputFlags.KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;

InputData[1].type = 1; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
InputData[1].wScan = (ushort)ScanCode;
InputData[1].dwFlags = (uint)(SendInputFlags.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 
                              | SendInputFlags.KEYEVENTF_UNICODE);

SendInput(2, InputData, Marshal.SizeOf(InputData[0]));
```

I'd start there.  It would be best to show the code you wrote that did not work using the method in the other post that appears to work.