# How to programatically press a key for an amount of time?

Tags: c#, winforms, key, keypress

So I know you can stimulate a keypress in C#, but my question is for example, I triggered an event, and I want the a specific key to be pressed.
Now that can be done using this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait(somechar);
```

But what if I want to press a key for a specific amount of time?
That can be done using this (Inside the event/trigger code block):

```
while(true)
{ SendKeys.SendWait(somechar); }
```

Although this would just cause the key to be a preponderance.

Now my question is, how do I actually make it so a key is being pressed the *whole time* (to keep the key pressed), and not that it would be pressed *many times* in a time instance instead?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342599/c-sharp-hold-key-in-a-game-application

Comment: why do you need such a behavior? `SendKeys` is "dirty" , maybe there is a better solution than using SendKeys.