# Is there a way to Send Numpad3 + Numpad4 keys while holding Left ALT in c# Windows Desktop Applicationto get double quotes?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have a desktop appcalition project which sends Keys with `SendKeys.Send()` function. I'm trying to send double quotes ("). **`SendKeys.Send("\\"")`;** **is not a solution for my project.** As you know another way to get (") is typing `34` on `numpad` while holding `Left Alt` on keyboard. That's exactly what I want to do. I want to Send `LALT+NUMPAD3+NUMPAD4`. I'm testing my compiled exe with `Wordpad application` on Windows 10. Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```cs
SendKeys.Send("\"");
```

It print `"` for me as the image below, but if you just want to sent `Alt+3+4` you can try

```cs
SendKeys.SendWait("%(34)");
```

The **`%`** is for **Alt**, `^` for **Ctrl** & `+` is for **Shift** so we are pressing **Alt** then typing `34` in the code above and it's just like

```cs
SendKeys.SendWait("+(vinod)");
```

that prints `VINOD` in `CAPS` because of `+` 'Ctrl` key.

> **The `SendKeys` will not differentiate between `Left Alt` or `Right Alt` perhaps you can use the `kebd_event` form the API please see the answer** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939988/3057246)

[image]