# Can an application block calls to SendInput?

Tags: winapi, automation, sendinput

There's a game that I'm trying to automate some actions on.

I've used [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) in the past very successfully. However, with this application I can't get the mouse click to work. I've tested it using other applications and it all works as expected.

Can applications block my use of SendInput? And if so, can I get around it somehow?

Side note: I'm writing code in C# and running on Windows 7 x64. The app I'm trying to interact with is x86. I don't know if this makes a difference? I've testing my code interacting with both x64 and x86 apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. (Not the call to `SendInput`, but the input can be filtered. See update below.)

If you look at the parameters for [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) there is nothing that identifies a process. The input is sent to the system, not an application. An application has no way of telling the difference between real and synthesized input.

There are a number of reasons why an application will not respond to synthesized input. As explained in the documentation for `SendInput` this API is subject to UIPI. An application running at a higher integrity level than an application calling `SendInput` will not receive this input.

Although `SendInput` injects input at a lower level than DirectInput runs, DirectInput is apparently more susceptible to buggy code. See [Simulating Keyboard with SendInput API in DirectInput applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications) for reference.

---

*Update (2016-05-01):*
Besides issues with UIPI, preventing input from reaching an application, it is also possible for a low-level keyboard/mouse hook to identify injected input. Both the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) (passed to the [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) callback) as well as the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx) (passed to the [LowLevelMouseProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx) callback) contain a *flags* member, that have the `LLKHF_INJECTED` or `LLMHF_INJECTED` flag set, in case the input is injected.

An application can thus install a low-level keyboard/mouse hook to filter out messages that are injected. If this is the case, a potential workaround (without writing a keyboard driver) is, to install a low-level keyboard/mouse hook **after** the application did, and prevent input to reach the application's hook by not calling `CallNextHookEx` (hooks are called in reverse order they are installed, from last to first).

Note: The workaround is deliberately short-circuiting installed hooks, thereby likely breaking other applications. Besides, if an application decided to implement a low-level hook to filter out injected input, it may just as well guard against competing low-level hooks by frequently re-installing itself to the top of the hook chain, this rendering the workaround useless.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I assume if I run as administrator, that would get round any UIPI problem? If that's the case, then I can discount that.