# Send keystrokes (numbers) to a game

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

By the way, i'm using VB.NET.

I tried many ways but i still can't figure out how to send keys to a game. By the way i'm trying to send numbers from the keyboard, not the keypad though, the normal numbers.
I tried:

```
SendKeys.Send("{1}")
```

or

```
SendKeys.Send(Chr(Keys.D1))
```

I tried those out but it doesn't work in the actual game, if i try it on something else like notepad it works.

Comment: What is the context of this question? I mean, what is this game you are talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the game Metin2 if that helps you in any way.

Comment: Probably should make sure the game is the focussed application first.

Comment: Where are you sending keys strokes from? Is the application listening for keystrokes to begin with? If so, why are you sending them? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation on SendKeys.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx), this command `Sends keystrokes to the active application.` Try clicking on the game's window, before you run the command.

If it does not help, check this out:

- [Simulating Keyboard with SendInput API in DirectInput applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a handler for the keystrokes like this:

```
AddHandler Main.KeyDown, AddressOf check_key
```

Then create a Sub to handle them like this:

```
Private Sub check_key(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

' When the Enter key is pressed, trigger the event 
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
            ' do something here
        End If
End Sub
```