# How to simulate holding down a keyboard button in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a program that would simulate holding down a keyboard button.

This program is supposed to work in games, where holding down buttons such as **W,A,S,D** is required. I tested the program both in Grand Theft Auto V and Garry's Mod, but it didn't work in either of them.

I tried using `SendInput` and `keybd_event` functions for emulating the input with no luck.

```
#include <windows.h>
#define VK_W 0x57

using namespace std;

int main(){
    while(1){
        keybd_event(VK_W, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(3000);  //should hold W for 3 seconds
        keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've created macros using Razer's keyboard software, which work perfectly, so there must be a way to simulate the key hold input.

I also tried creating an `AutoHotkey` script, which does work in Garry's Mod, but not in Grand Theft Auto V:

```
w::
SendInput {w down}
Sleep 3000
SendInput {w up}
```

This script holds W for 3 seconds when **W** is pressed.

I tried searching the web, but didn't find any working implementation.

**EDIT: I searched around some more and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647975/1587051**

**It turns out I was using Unicode instead of keyboard scan codes combined with `KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE` flag. DirectInput games are now receiving the keystrokes correctly.**

Comment: Have you tried in an app with a message loop? For functions related to input events, it's not crazy to think a message loop is required to complete the process.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a message loop, could you elaborate?

Comment: Most games use DirectInput or the likes and don't respond to window messages. That means that `keybd_event`, `SendMessage` and related don't work.

Comment: *"I've created macros using Razer's keyboard software [...] so there must be a way to simulate the key hold input."* Of course there is: Write yourself a mouse driver that pretends that the user did produce mouse input, like the Razer software does.

Comment: Writing a driver seems like an overkill for such a task. I tried doing it again with SendInput, this time with Unicode - no luck.

Comment: @MicroVirus is there a way, without writing a driver, to force keystrokes into DirectInput application?

Comment: Like @MicroVirus said, such games, especially in full-screen mode just ignore Windows messages and take input directly from the mouse/keyboard. Your only way to simulate that is by writing a modified driver. Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications

Comment: @JameyD Thanks, this is exactly what I already had a look at (see Edit), and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference sake, as it has already been answered in the comments, you have to use `SendInput` rather than `SendMessage`, when filling the `INPUT` structure required for the `SendInput` function make sure you combine your `Flags` with `KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE` to send hardware signals instead of virtual ones. These will be handled by DirectInput.
Source : [Simulating Keyboard with SendInput API in DirectInput applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications/3647975#3647975)